# Statement.getGeneratedKeys() returns nothing SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a table and I want to insert a row and return generatedkey (primary key). Here is my pseudo code:

```
int records = jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().update(connection -> {

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertEventMaster, new String[] { EVENT_ID });
int index = 1;
statement.setLong(index++, event.getActionAccount().getUser().getId());
statement.setString(index++, event.getType());
statement.setString(index++, event.getDetail());
statement.setString(index++, event.getStatus());
statement.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()), CALENDAR);
statement.executeUpdate();
try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        long event_id = (generatedKeys.getLong(1));
    }
}
return statement;
```

when `statement.getGeneratedKeys()`, it has nothing in it, and `event_id` is always 0, when I am expecting 1 (or higher). I think it is something to do with my database table setup. Here is DDL I have from the table:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA.dbo.EVENT_MASTER (
    EVENT_ID numeric(38,0) NOT NULL,
    SMR_USER_ID numeric(38,0) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL,
    DETAIL varchar(4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL,
    STATUS varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL,
    TRANSACTION_REFERENCE varchar(1024) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL,
    UPDATE_TIMESTAMP datetime2(6) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_C00254058 PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID)
) GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EVTID_STATUS_IND ON dbo.EVENT_MASTER (  EVENT_ID ASC  , STATUS ASC  )  
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,FILLFACTOR = 100  ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , ONLINE = OFF , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
     ON [PRIMARY ]  GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EVNTMSTR_USRIDX ON dbo.EVENT_MASTER (  USER_ID ASC  )  
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,FILLFACTOR = 100  ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , ONLINE = OFF , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
     ON [PRIMARY ]  GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EVENT_MASTER_TYPE_TS_IDX ON dbo.EVENT_MASTER (  TYPE ASC  )  
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,FILLFACTOR = 100  ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , ONLINE = OFF , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
     ON [PRIMARY ]  GO;


-- PSH_DATA.dbo.EVENT_MASTER foreign keys

ALTER TABLE DATA.dbo.EVENT_MASTER ADD CONSTRAINT EVENT_MASTER_USER_ID FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES DATA.dbo.USERS(ID) GO;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is `event_id` missing the [`IDENTITY` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: hmm.. so I read about this and wasn't sure how to do that for `event_id` column. I figured having `CONSTRAINT SYS_C00254058 PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID)` was enough..?

Comment: That just makes it the primary key. Primary keys don't have to be auto-assigned by the database, so you have to explicitly tell the database, if you want auto-increment / identity / whatever the database in question calls it.

Comment: I will try `EVENT_ID numeric(38,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,`